# typeORM No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, typeorm

I'm doing a course where we are using express-node postgres and react (with typescript) and typeORM. Everything has worked well so far, but I'm facing an issue with typeORM and I don't know what is going and why is this error happening

**The Big Problem** : So, the problem is that, I was doing the auth, and at some point we changed users schema in the DB so we had to make a migration, but, before migration, we did `npm run typeorm schema:drop` ,but when I tried, this happened with migration

This is the first command I used

```
npm run typeorm migration:generate -- --n create-users-table
```

This was the error

```
> new-typeorm-project@0.0.1 typeorm C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit> ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js "migration:generate" "create-users-table"

bin.js migration:generate

Generates a new migration file with sql needs to be executed to update
schema.

Opciones:
  -h, --help          Muestra ayuda                             [booleano]  -c, --connection    Name of the connection on which run a query.
                                                      [defecto: "default"]  -n, --name          Name of the migration class.
                                        [cadena de caracteres] [requerido]  -d, --dir           Directory where migration should be created.
  -p, --pretty        Pretty-print generated SQL
                                               [booleano] [defecto: false]  -f, --config        Name of the file with connection configuration.
                                                    [defecto: "ormconfig"]  -o, --outputJs      Generate a migration file on Javascript instead of
                      Typescript               [booleano] [defecto: false]      --dr, --dryrun  Prints out the contents of the migration instead of
                      writing it to a file     [booleano] [defecto: false]      --ch, --check   Verifies that the current database is up to date and                      that no migrations are needed. Otherwise exits with
                      code 1.                  [booleano] [defecto: false]  -v, --version       Muestra número de versión                 [booleano]
Falta argumento requerido: n
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! new-typeorm-project@0.0.1 typeorm: `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js "migration:generate" "create-users-table"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the new-typeorm-project@0.0.1 typeorm script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\diego cifuentes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-11T15_29_02_081Z-debug.log
```

After hours trying to search for solution everywhere, I change the last command to this one

```
npx typeorm migration:generate -- --n create-users-table
```

And the error was different this time, looks like this

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

So, I said, ok, I'm getting closer to fixing this, but... After hours ( again ) looking for a new answer, I couldn't find anything, so, I'm getting to a point where I need to write this post in order to fix my problem. So now, let me show you my ormconfig, my package.json and the entity I want to migrate in my postgres DB.

package.json (the script typeorm is at the end)

```
{
  "name": "new-typeorm-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.2",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "typeorm": "0.2.32"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/server.ts",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  }
}
```

ormconfing.json **Quick note** : I changed entities, migrations and subscribers to .js, because with .ts was always giving me error.

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "**",
  "password": "**",
  "database": "**",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["src/entities/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["src/migrations/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscribers/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entities",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migrations",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscribers"
  }
}
```

And last thing I want to show you, even though it might not be that important, this is the users schema

```
import {
  Entity as TOEntity,
  Column,
  Index,
  BeforeInsert,
  OneToMany
} from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { IsEmail, Length } from "class-validator";
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";

import Entity from "./Entity";
// import Post from "./Post";

@TOEntity("users")
export default class User extends Entity {
  constructor(user: Partial<User>) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, user);
  }

  @Index()
  @IsEmail()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Index()
  @Length(3, 200)
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Length(6, 200)
  @Column()
  password: string;

  // @OneToMany(() => Post, post => post.user)
  // posts: Post[];

  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashedPassword() {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 6);
  }
}
```

**End Goal**: So, if you can help me with this, you will save my life. One last thing is that I tried to post my problems first in the Spanish website of stack overflow, but nobody could help me, so maybe here someone will, thanks for your time and take care!

Answer (score 10):

Change your `entities`, `migrations` and `subscribers` into your `dist` directory.

e.g.:

```js
  entities: ["dist/entities/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
  migrations: ["dist/migrations/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
  subscribers: ["dist/subscribers/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
```

`dist` directory is the directory which gets created when you build the app. You can find your `dist` directory using `tsconfig.json` -> `compilerOptions` -> `outDir`.

Then build your app again using `npm run build` and try to generate the migrations.

Comment: In my tsconfig. in outDir appears './build' so, should i change that to build ? 

And actually, thinkinh about the problem i had, i think it might be because of i leave synchronize true, when i do migrations i should put it in false?

And thanks for answering me !

Comment: Yes, you should change it to build and make synchronize to false it as well

Comment: All right man, thank you  for your answer !!

Comment: I made the changes, i first used npm run typeorm, and it gives me the initial error i mentioned in the post, then, i tried to use npx, and it appears the same message, No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command.

I don't understand :/

Comment: It is because since you had synchronize to true earlier, the database is already up to date with your entity classes. What you need to do is delete the database, create a new empty database with the same name, and then try to generate the migrations. Then you will have the migrations generated to create all your tables from the scratch if this is the first time you are going to create the migrations. If you need your data in the database, but still want to create the migrations then the procedure is a little bit complex. So comment here if that is the case. I just gave you the easiest solution

Comment: I get it, so, i should put sinchronize at the beggining of the development of the backend ? I think that might be the issue, next app i'll change that then

Comment: Correct. Or you can empty all your tables (kind of similar to deleting the database and creating a new one), then try to create a new migration

Comment: There is another way. You can create a new empty database using a different name to what you already have. Then change `database` parameter in typeorm connection options to that new database, and then try to generate the migrations. `synchronize` should be `false` at all the time when you're doing this. But you will still not be able to run migrations on your current database. If you need to do it, it is still possible but complex

Comment: Deleting my local schema and then re-running the migration (followed @ErangaHeshan steps) and got me past same error as Diego posted

Answer (score 3):

For me the ormconfig.json's was like this,

```
   "entities": [
      "dist/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
```

Changing it to

```
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*{.js,.ts}"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*{.js,.ts}"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*{.js,.ts}"
   ],
```

generated the migration correctly.

And the package.json script is like this
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"

And the command used is

npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n FileAddTemporaryDeletedFields -p --dr --ch

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error, and if I'm not mistaken it's because I was trying to create a bank that had already been created.

**This command below deletes all tables:**

`yarn typeorm query "DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public; GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to PUBLIC; GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public to PUBLIC; COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';"`

**then:**

`yarn typeorm --migration:generate -n migration_name -d path/to/your/migrations/`

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue. It couldn't read the Entities with given path I think the problem happened due to file permission issue or something.

**so I have changed**

```
entities: ['src/app/entities/*{.ts,.js}']
```

**to**

```
entities: [Role,User]
```

and It works fine, don't forget to import your entities like

```
import { Role } from '../entities/role.entity';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
```

Comment: one extra thing is by doing the import approach is that you can see errors more clear like " Entity "XXXEntity" does not have a primary column. Primary column is required to have in all your entities. Use @PrimaryColumn decorator to add a primary column to your entity.
". So thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If someone is as silly as me, I had named my entity file wrong and it was not recognising them.

Wrong file name:

`file_name_entity.ts`

Correct file name:

`file_name.entity.ts`

Notice the . in the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

ormconfig.json is deprecated in latest version as i know.
but anyway I'm gonna share my solution when i used old version.

when generate, typeorm first reads ormconfig.json and login into rdbms.
and compares between 'the actual schema of db' and
'schema file as ormconfig.json[entities]'

so, if the file (writen at 'entities' in ormconfig.json) is in dist folder.
you have to edit that .js file.(not .ts file in src folder)

but, if the 'entities' file is in src folder as ormconfig.json,
check if 'autosave' feature of vscode is on.
if you 'npm run start:dev'
It could be the case that the actual schema of db has been already modified
before you edit entities file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use sqlite as a database make sure that yout data-source.ts file is wrote like this:

```
export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: 'db.sqlite',
  entities: ['**/*.entity*{.js,.ts}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/*{.js,.ts}'],
} as DataSourceOptions);
```

This will eliminate the effect of the wrong file extension.

And also delete your db.sqlite file  from your project folder, before you run 'migration:generate'

Answer (score 0):

Change your entity model then make sure that entities path is correct.

```
entities: ['./**/*.entity.ts'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and in my case it was a rather simple case of human error: config paths were all set correctly and it did generate a migration before. However, I forgot the `export` in the entity class definition so typeorm couldn't load the entity :-/